# Creating a if..then type rule (constraint) in Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I am new to Pyomo. I want to add an if..then.. type constraint to my linear programming problem. I have an abstract model and this is an example what I'd like to do:

if node j1 is receiving less than half of its water demand, the minimum flow in the link between j2 and j1 must be set to demand value in j1 (A and B are model variables, d is a known parameter).

```
if A(j1)<0.5 then B(j2,j1)>=d(j1)
```

I tried the following when I define model constraints. But since the model has not yet created the instance from its data file, it doesn't recognize j1 and j2.

```
def rule_(model):
    term1=floor(model.A[j1]/0.5)
    return (term1*model.B[j1,j2]>term1*mdoel.demand[j1])
model.rule=Constraint(rule=rule_)
```

If I take these lines after instantiating the model using data file, I think the constraint will not be implemented at all.

Can anyone help with this, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"If/then" expressions and `floor()` are not linear, so they can't be inserted directly into a linear program. However, you can get the same effect by setting a binary flag and using that to activate and deactivate the constraint. Note that binary variables are also not linear, but they are commonly handled by mixed-integer solvers.

```
model.flag = Var(within=Binary)
def set_flag_rule(model):
    # force the flag to be set if A[j1] < 0.5
    return ((1 - model.flag) * 0.5 <= model.A[j1])
model.set_flag = Constraint(rule=set_flag_rule)

def rule(model):
    # force B[j1, j2] to meet demand if the flag is set
    return (model.B[j1,j2] >= model.flag * model.demand[j1])
model.rule=Constraint(rule=rule)
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped a great deal. However, I'd like to point out that the constraint you proposed to force the flag will not work properly. A[j1] is between 0 and 1, perhaps I should have mentioned this in my question . I think the best way is to force the flag using two constraints:
    def set_flag_rule_one(model):
         return ((1 - model.flag) * 0.5>= model.A['j1']-0.5)
    model.set_flag_one = Constraint(rule=set_flag_rule_one)
    def set_flag_rule_two(model):
        return (-model.flag * 0.5<= model.A['j1]-10)
    model.set_flag_two = Constraint(rule=set_flag_rule_two)

Comment: But there is one issue. Even with these two constraints only (and not using the 'rule' constraint) the model gives different solutions compared to when there were none of these lines. Why is that happening?!

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this. An easy answer is to let Pyomo do the hard work using disjunctions.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import pyomo.gdp as gdp

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.J = pyo.Set(initialize=["j1", "j2"])
model.demand = pyo.Param(model.J, initialize=1)
model.A = pyo.Var(model.J, bounds=(0, 1))
model.B = pyo.Var(model.J, model.J, bounds=(0, 10))

@model.Disjunction()
def rule(model):
    disjunct_A = [
        model.A["j1"] <= 0.5, 
        model.B["j2", "j1"] >= model.demand["j1"]
    ]
    disjunct_B = [model.A["j1"] >= 0.5]
    return [disjunct_A, disjunct_B]

@model.Objective(sense=pyo.maximize)
def obj(model):
    return model.A["j1"]

pyo.TransformationFactory('gdp.bigm').apply_to(model)
pyo.SolverFactory('appsi_highs').solve(model)

print(model.A["j1"](), model.B["j2", "j1"]())
```